# Syntax Error CREATE TABLE Statement

Tags: ms-access, syntax

i am getting a Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.  Microsoft Access 2007.

```
CREATE TABLE ROOMS
(
RoomNum Int Not Null,
RoomSize Char(6) Not Null,
RoomBedCnt Int Not Null,
RoomRate Numeric(18,2) Not Null,
CONSTRAINT ROOM_PK PRIMARY KEY (RoomNum)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `NUMBER` data type instead of `NUMERIC(18,2)`, which is a SQL Server data type.  Also, the `CHAR` column should be `TEXT`...  Use the visual designer to design your table; it will force you to choose from valid data types, and will automatically generate the correct syntax.

See the [MSDN Microsoft Access Data Types page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

It seems like you are familiar with SQL Server T-SQL syntax, why don't you use SQL Server Express, which is free, instead of Microsoft Access?